# Why do I see a deviation when I compare PDBs using TMalign?

Tags: proteins, pdb

I constructed a PDB file of main-chain from its CA-trace using `pd2_ca2main` app. I used [`TMalign`](https://zhanggroup.org/TM-align/) to compute RMSD values from those two files.

[The research paper of TMaligh](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1084323/) says that:

> "TM-align only employs the backbone Cα coordinates of the given protein structures; however, the methodology is readily generalized to any type of atom."

Therefore, the source PDB and the resultant PDB have the same CAs. Right? If so, why do I see a deviation when I compare the source PDB and the resultant PDB?

Comment: Cross posted on [bioinfo SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19878/how-can-i-compare-two-pdb-files/) AND [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9542402/). Bad form, OP.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9542402/) to see more discussion about this question.

If someone wants to write a more detailed answered here, this Community Wiki can be deleted.